# Photoshop file is showing blank

Tags: photoshop-cs6

I created a file in Photoshop and saved it. Then I turned off my laptop and left it for one day. After one day I opened Photoshop and tried to open that particular file and it would not open. The page is showing blank instead of showing that file. Other Photoshop files are opening normally. Only this file has a problem.

What should I do to correctly display the contents of this Photoshop file?

Comment: is it the correct layer?

Comment: yeah @Scorpion99

Comment: Can you upload the file? (dropbox/drive)

Answer (score 0):

A blank photoshop document (PSD) is about 120 KB. If your file is around that size then there isn't anything that can be done with that file.